# Flask API with variable output defined by url

Tags: python, json, api, flask

I am writing an API using flask.

I would like the API to return either the elements in the column category or in the column subcategory of my table category depending on the url.

eg http:.../categories/subcategory or http:.../categories/category

I have tried to create the variable `category_type` and to assign it to the output d but it does not work.

```
 class Categories(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'categories'
      category = db.Column(db.Text)
      subcategory = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key = True)

 @app.route('/categories/<string:category_type>', methods=['GET'])
 def categories(category_type):
     if request.method == 'GET':
         results = Categories.query.all()

         json_results = []
         for result in results:
             d = {'Category': result.category_type}
             json_results.append(d)

         return jsonify(items=json_results)
```

Comment: `result.category_type` isn't defined in the Categories class.   Perhaps you want a filter?

Comment: 'Category': category_type should be enough

Comment: unfortunately not it returns the name of the column in my db but I would like the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change categories method similar below:

```
@app.route('/categories/<string:category_type>', methods=['GET'])
def categories(category_type):
    if category_type.lower() not in ('category', 'subcagory'):
        flask.abort(404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        results = Categories.query.all()

        json_results = []
        for result in results:
            d = {'Category': getattr(result, category_type.lower())}
            json_results.append(d)

        return jsonify(items=json_results)
```

**Update**: if you want remove duplicates change `json_results` variable type to `set` similar below:

```
@app.route('/categories/<string:category_type>', methods=['GET'])
def categories(category_type):
    if category_type.lower() not in ('category', 'subcagory'):
        flask.abort(404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        results = Categories.query.all()

        json_results = set()
        for result in results:
            d = {'Category': getattr(result, category_type.lower())}
            json_results.add(d)

        return jsonify(items=json_results)
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could tell me how to remove duplicates?